# how to force to wait for the second selection on jquery change

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, onchange

I have one text box and one select box

```
<input type="text" name="TourDate"  id="TourDate" class="date form-control input-sm" value="">
<select name="TourID" id="TourID" class="form-control">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

After I enter the date (via boostrap calendar) and select the tour I would like to refresh the page

```
$(function(){
    $('.form-control').on('change',function(){
        keyword = '_kfnTourID:equal:'+$('#TourID').val()+'|';
        keyword += '_kfdTourDate:equal:'+$('#TourDate').val();
        window.location.href = "{{ url('bookings?search=') }}"+keyword ;
    })
})
```

But it refreshes the page after I select the date can you please show me how to force to wait for the second selection? also while is refreshed I would like to show `loading...` on the screen until the refreshing is finished. I am new at this would appreciate your help.

Comment: Validate the 2 values first and don't redirect if they don't validate. This is extremely common

Comment: can you write me an example please as I said I am new at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate each fields having class `form-control` if one of them is not set then just `exit` using `return`.Like below.

```
$(function(){
    $('.form-control').on('change',function(){
       if($('#TourDate').val()=="" || $('#TourID').val()==0){
            return;///it exit the execution of code below it
          }
        keyword= '_kfdTourDate:equal:'+$('#TourDate').val();
        keyword+= '_kfnTourID:equal:'+$('#TourID').val()+'|';

        window.location.href = "{{ url('bookings?search=') }}"+keyword ;
    });
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('.form-control').on('change',function(){
       if($('#TourDate').val()=="" || $('#TourID').val()==0){
            return;///it exit the execution of code below it
          }
        keyword= '_kfdTourDate:equal:'+$('#TourDate').val();

        keyword+= '_kfnTourID:equal:'+$('#TourID').val()+'|';

        window.location.href = "{{ url('bookings?search=') }}"+keyword ;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="TourDate"  id="TourDate" class="date form-control input-sm" value="">
<select name="TourID" id="TourID" class="form-control">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Must validate both. User may not change the controls in order elements are shown

Comment: @ charlietfl yes agree with you.

Comment: Can be done in one `if()` . No need to duplcate code. Also no need to search dom numerous times

Comment: it worked thank you very much. can you give me any sample/link that would help me to understand how to show   `loading..` when the page is refreshing?

Comment: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview take some reference from here.